# Restrict access to Repository based on IP address

Tags: svn, authorization, access-control, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

We have several repositories within our VisualSVN. However one of the repositories should be restricted based on the IP address of the computer from which it is accessed ie. it can be accessed only from one particular computer and it should deny access from others.

Is there a way we can do this? If so could you please help with the code.

Note: The restriction is not to the entire VisualSVN but only to a specific repository. Kindly do not suggest a thread where they suggest how to restrict the entire VisualSVN for some public IPs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict in VisualSVN Server access only to some specific public IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847448/how-to-restrict-in-visualsvn-server-access-only-to-some-specific-public-ips)

Comment: The thread above does not have the solution I need. Please do not suggest that.

Comment: Do you need Read Only / Read Write and No Access permissions based on IP. Or will "Deny from certain IP" help?

Comment: @bahrep , the repository should be accessible only from one particular IP ie. allow for one IP and deny for rest